# sql create table with stored procedure with optional parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, parameters, create-table

I am writing a report based on parameters, utilizing a sql stored procedure. Problem is there are several 'optional' parameters, where the user can choose a value, or ignore that parameter altogether. I need to use the stored proc as a dataset in asp.net report. Only way I thought of doing it is to create a table from the results. But I'm clueless.

How do I turn this into a 'create table' stored proc?
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Cindy

This is what I have so far -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rspSCL]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
(@year as int,
@RRID as int,
@State as nchar(2),
@Sub as varchar(75),
@app as int,
@sprayed as int,
@subcontracted as int,
@thirdapp as bit)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
DECLARE @SQL as varchar(4000)
DECLARE @SUBQ AS varchar(400)


--what fields need to be seen
SET @SQL = 'SELECT C.CRID, C.DOT, C.RR, C.Pref, C.MP, C.Division,  C.Subdivision,C.City, C.Street,
    C.State, C.County, C.RestrictedCounty, C.Remarks, C.SpecialInstructions, C.Route, C.ThirdAppRequired,
    C.MainTrks, C.OtherTrks, C.OnSpur, C.MaxSpeed, C.SubContracted, C.FenceEncroachment, C.Lat, C.Long,
    C.PropertyType, C.WarningDevice,C.Surface, C.ROWNE, C.ROWNW, C.ROWSE, C.ROWSW, C.ROWWidth, C.ExtNE,
    C.ExtNW, C.ExtSE, C.ExtSW, C.TempActive, A.Spray, A.ContractYear' 


   SET @SUBQ =
   CASE WHEN @app = 1 THEN
    'FROM Crossings LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select A.CRID, A.spray FROM ApplicationData A 
    WHERE A.ContractYear = '  + CAST( @year AS varchar(4)) + ') as APPS
    ON Crossings.CRID = APPS.CRID' 

  WHEN @app = 2 THEN
     'FROM Crossings inner join
    (SELECT crid, C,OUNT(APPID)as count
    from ApplicationData
    where ContractYear = ' + CAST( @year AS varchar(4)) + '
    group by CRID) as APPS

    ON Crossings.CRID = APPS.CRID
    WHERE Crossings.RR = '+ CAST( @RRID AS varchar(4)) + '
    and crossings.state = '+ @state + '
    and count = 1'

when @app = 3 THEN
   'FROM Crossings inner join
    (SELECT crid, COUNT(APPID)as count
    from ApplicationData
    where ContractYear = ' + CAST( @year AS varchar(4)) + '
    group by CRID) as APPS

    ON Crossings.CRID = APPS.CRID
    WHERE Crossings.RR = '+ CAST( @RRID AS varchar(4)) + '
    and crossings.state = '+ @state + '
    and count = 2'  
ELSE ''
END

--add the FROM to the query
SET @SQL = @SQL + @SUBQ


--add the subdivision to the where statement
If @Sub != 'ALL'
 SET @SQL = @SQL + 'AND (C.Subdivision = ' + @Sub + ')'
ELSE
 SET @SQL = @SQL

--add sprayed to where
DECLARE @S as varchar(100)
SET @S =
CASE WHEN @sprayed = 1 THEN
    'AND (A.sprayed = 1)'
WHEN @sprayed = 0 THEN
    'AND (A.sprayed = 0)'
ELSE
    ''
END

SET @SQL = @SQL + @S

--add subcontracted to where
DECLARE @C as varchar (100)
SET @C = 
CASE WHEN @subcontracted = 0 THEN
    'AND (C.subcontracted = 0)'
WHEN @subcontracted = 1 THEN
    'AND (C.subcontracted = 1)'
ELSE
    ''
END 

SET @SQL = @SQL + @C

IF @thirdapp = 1
SET @SQL = @SQL + 'AND (C.ThirdAppRequired = 1)'
ELSE
SET @SQL = @SQL

END
```

Comment: why would you want to create a table?

Comment: hope this link helps you http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Stored_Procedures_-_Executing_%26_Dynamic_SQL

Comment: I need to have fields available to choose from in my dataset. The way it's currently written, I don't have visible fields that show up on asp.net for the dataset. I'm open to all ideas.

Comment: kreshekhar - the link helped explain things, but i still can't figure out how to make the fields available.